# Powershell: append text after string in file

Tags: regex, powershell, text, tags, append

Problem: I am trying to append a string after a tag. I got a large text file, and I only need to append some text after the tag (including the text xxxxxx) `<xxxxxx>`, and I cannot seem to figure it out just yet.

Currently im trying this with regex: `<[(xxxxxx)]+>`, which according to regex101.com does match the exact tag `<xxxxxx>`, but when I use this in Powershell it returns a lot of other stuff.

How can I make sure that Powershell only matches `<xxxxxx>` ? And to append some string after `<xxxxxx>` ?

Sample snippet from the text file: `PredefinedSettings=<xxxxxx><abc test123 /abc></xxxxxx>`

Sample PS command: `Get-Content .\samplefile.ini | Select-String -Pattern "<[(xxxxxx)]+>"`

Which returns the entire line `PredefinedSettings=<xxxxxx><abc test123 /abc></xxxxx>` instead of just `<xxxxxx>`

Comment: Could you please add the PS code you are using?

Comment: But why don't you `-replace` / `.Replace` if you need to append some text? Like `(Get-Content $f).Replace("<xxxxxx>", "<xxxxxx>SOME TEXT")` if `<xxxxxx>` is hardcoded? Why regex, BTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output just the matched text, you can do the following:

```
Select-String -Path sample.ini -Pattern '<(/?xxxxxx)>' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value # Outputs matched text between `<>`
    $_.Matches.Value # Outputs all matched text
}
```

The `-AllMatches` switch will allow matching beyond the first match. So it would return `<xxxxxx>` and `</xxxxxx>`.

---

If you want to replace text in a file, you can do the following:

```
(Get-Content .\samplefile.ini) -replace '<(/?xxxxxx)>','<$1Text>' |
    Set-Content .\sampplefile.ini
```

If your replacement text is in a variable, you will need to escape the `$` for the capture group.

```
$Text = 'replacement Text'
(Get-Content .\samplefile.ini) -replace '<(/?xxxxxx)>',"<`$1$Text>" |
    Set-Content .\sampplefile.ini
```

`$1` is the capture group `1` data matched within the first `()`. Depending on your `Text`, it may be wise to name your capture group. If `Text` is `23OtherText`, `<$123OtherText>` will attempt to substitute capture group `123`. Using a named capture group, you can do the following:

```
(Get-Content .\samplefile.ini) -replace '<(?<Tag>/?xxxxxx)>','<${Tag}Text>' |
    Set-Content .\sampplefile.ini
```

`/?` matches zero or more `/` characters.

`-replace` will return all text not matched and all text replaced by the operator.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right.

In regex Quantifiers are greedy so it will select from the first open tag to the last closing tag, you can change that by using a `?`.

So your Regex will be `<[(xxxxxx)]+?>`.